# Ruby on rails Active Storage Validations not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activestorage

I am using:

**Rails 6.0.4.4**

**Ruby 3.0.0**

I have added `gem'active_storage_validations'` to my project, and am trying to use it to validate that **attached avatars are images**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable, :confirmable, :trackable, :lockable, :masqueradable
         
  validates :first_name, :last_name, presence: true
  validates :email, uniqueness: true
  validates :terms_and_conditions, acceptance: true
  validates :avatar, attached: true,  content_type: ['image/png', 'image/jpg', 'image/jpeg']
  has_one_attached :avatar
end
```

in my sign_up form

```
<%= render "devise/shared/error_messages", resource: resource %>
<div class="container pt-3 pb-3">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
      <h2>Sign up</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <%= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
        <div class="field mb-3">
          <%= f.label :profile_picture %><br />
          <%= f.file_field :avatar, class: "form-control"  %>
        </div>
        <div class="field mb-3">
          <%= f.label :email %><br />
            <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, autocomplete: "email", class: "form-control", placeholder: "name@email.com" %>
        </div>
        <div class="field mb-3">
          <%= f.label :first_name %><br />
            <%= f.text_field :first_name, required: true, autofocus: true, autocomplete: "first_name", class: "form-control" %>
        </div>
        <div class="field mb-3">
          <%= f.label :last_name %><br />
            <%= f.text_field :last_name, autofocus: true, autocomplete: "last_name", class: "form-control" %>
        </div>
        <div class="field mb-3">
          <%= f.label :password %>
          <% if @minimum_password_length %>
          <em>(<%= @minimum_password_length %> characters minimum)</em>
          <% end %><br />
          <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "new-password", class: "form-control" %>
        </div>
        <div class="field mb-3">
          <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
          <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "new-password", class: "form-control" %>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check form-switch text-muted">
          <%= f.check_box :terms_and_conditions, class: 'form-check-input', id: 'flexSwitchCheckDefault' %>
          I hereby confirm I have read and undertood the terms and conditions
        </div>
        <div class="actions">
          <%= f.submit "Continue", class: "btn btn-primary"  %>
        </div>
      <% end %>
      <br>
    <%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: Eroor image]

All the other validations work fine.

**If I add validations for file type or size on the attached image, it still allows the user to upload any file type and size**

Comment: Avatar can't be blank -- it looks validation is working

Comment: It works on that one validation, but not `content_type: ['image/png', 'image/jpg', 'image/jpeg']`

Comment: @Lorenzo_xavier did you ever figure this out? I'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I am a maintainer of the `active_storage_validation` gem, I am unsure of you are expecting here.

First you need to restrict the user input on the UI part, this stands in the accept HTML attribute, ie `accept="image/png, image/jpg, image/jpeg"` in your input element. With this, you user will only be able to upload these content types files, this will enhance the UX.

Then you will have validations running on the model, that where `active_storage_validation` comes into play. The `content_type` validator has the following guard clause (`return true unless record.send(attribute).attached?` ([here](https://github.com/igorkasyanchuk/active_storage_validations/blob/master/lib/active_storage_validations/content_type_validator.rb#L21))), so if you do not attach anything is does not raise an error. This reduces the number of errors sent.

I think that adding the `accept` HTML attribute will solve most of your cases.

If not, we can discuss this in the gem repo with an issue